# Any way to ensure that <div> follow their width property defined in CSS

Tags: css, html

`<div>s` are extremely notorious in their nature. for example :- Incase the divs are empty, they just don't follow their width property defined in CSS. Is there a way to ensure that the div's follow their width property set in CSS even when they are empty.

Actually in a dynamic application, i have four floating divs next to each other. Incase any of the div contain no data, the following div take its place. Is there a way to ensure that this thing doesn't happen

Comment: put an `&nbsp;` in your `<div>` - s

Comment: extremely stupid of me. :-) ... Thanks... BTW this seems to be hack. This way i will always i have one space before my text. Anyways there's nothing else one can do

Comment: `<div>&nbsp;</div>` is a bit hacky, but seems to be the only way.

Comment: @Smamatti : it doesn't work but thanks....It seemed a solution so i tried but to no avail :-(

Comment: @SimoneVittori vittori what do you mean by hit hacky well I wanted to know what happens if we use in that way ? I just want to know

Comment: @PankajUpadhyay You may have done something wrong. It's working fine foe me: http://jsfiddle.net/z4PWU/

Comment: They sure seem to follow their width properties just fine to me, without any hacks. Just use the CSS `width` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the `&nbsp;` in the `div` tag that will do the trick

Comment: Your code is incorrect... it's missing a `;`.  Should be `&nbsp;`.

Comment: @Sparky672 I got what you meant Thanks

Answer (score 2):

### Solution

Use `min-width`.

#### Sample

http://jsfiddle.net/z4PWU/

#### HTML

```
<!-- Empty floating divs -->
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<br />

<!-- Non-Empty floating divs -->
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<br />

<!-- min/max width for floating divs -->
<div style="min-width:50px;"></div>
<div style="min-width:50px;"></div>
<div style="min-width:50px;"></div>
```

#### CSS

```
div {
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    height: 15px; /* Make them better visible */
}
```